# How to import object of a class in python

Tags: python

I had a class in as below in module practice.
practice/example.py

```
class Example :

    #some code#

e1= Example();
e2= Example();
```

and I had `practice/__init__.py`

```
from example import Example
```

and i had main.py

```
import sys , python_practice


e3 = python_practice.Example();


from python_practice import *

e1.sum(1,2);
```

but i am getting error as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "practice.py", line 11, in <module>
e1.sum(1,2);
NameError: name 'e1' is not defined
```

Where I went wrong....

Is it possible to import the object of the class to another module ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you just have to import it.

When you do `from python_practice import *`, you get everything defined in `practice/__init__.py`.  In that `__init__.py`, you don't import `e1`, so you don't import it with `from python_practice import *` either.

If you want `e1` to be available at the top level `python_practice`, you need to import it in `__init__.py`.  Change your code there to `from example import Example, e1, e2`.

Comment: If suppose i didn't had __init__.py in the python_practice module how can i import the object ? Is there any other way of doing it.

Comment: If you don't have `__init__.py` you don't have a package at all, so you can't import it at all.  If you had the `practice` directory directly on the path, you could import it with `from example import Example, e1, e2`, but it probably would not be a good idea to create a top-level package named `example`.

Comment: Hello BrenBarn..... Thank you for the help. Now i had a different issue. I wnat some help. In the above exaple i know the instance of the class as e1 or e2. But in my application i am managed to get the object name as string. with that string how can i will be able to access the object.

Comment: @mkreddy: You should ask that as a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

`__init__` sets up the namespace for your package.  Since `__init__` imports `Example`, then `Example` is available in the package namespace (e.g. `python_practice.Example`).  `e1` is *not* available there because nothing you did in `__init__` makes `e1` available there.

Of course, you can pretty much always get there ...

```
from python_practice.example import e1
```

should work.